# How to reduce variance of sample mean?

Tags: variance, sampling, law-of-large-numbers

According to the law of large number, Var$(\bar{X}_n)=\sigma^2/n$. Is there any methods I can do to reduce the variance without increasing the number of samples ($n$)?

Comment: While drawing from the same distribution? No. Usually what you do is to draw from a different distribution that you somehow know has the same true mean as the one of interest, but has a lower variance, and then sample from that instead.

Comment: By the way, the scaling of the variance is only indirectly related to LLN, which doesn't require finite variance at all. All it really tells you is a bound on the convergence rate in WLLN in the finite variance case (through Chebyshev's inequality).